# How to schedule recurring lambda executions without using unreliable town clock

Tags: aws-lambda

I saw that there is a community supported way of triggering AWS lambda functions in a recurring time, but is there an official AWS implementation of this kind of trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon has announced that AWS Lambda now supports Scheduled Functions:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-update-python-vpc-increased-function-duration-scheduling-and-more/

You can set this up in the AWS console.

In fact, the Unreliable Town Clock mentioned in your question is itself now powered by AWS Lambda Scheduled Functions on the back end.

https://alestic.com/2015/10/townclock-aws-lambda-scheduled-functions-cron/

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `Lambda` subscribed to a `SNS Topic` and then a simple script running on your server that sends a message to the `SNS Topic` which triggers all `Lambda` functions subscribed. Your script can be executed by a `cron` job.

Something like this in Ruby:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'aws-sdk'

topic = 'arn:aws:sns:<region>:<account id>:<SNS Topic id>'

sns = Aws::SNS::Client.new(
    access_key_id: '<key>',
    secret_access_key: '<secret>',
    region: '<SNS Topic region>'
)

r = sns.publish({
    topic_arn: topic,
    message: 'execute'
})

puts r.inspect
```